# Using a grayscale image to create an RGB image with matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a grayscale image and I want this image as the three bands of an RGB image. In other words, each band of the new RGB image will be this grayscale image

That's what i tried so far:

```
gray_image=imread('image.pgm');
rgb_image=zeros(size(gray_image,1),size(gray_image,2),3);
rgb_image(:,:,1)=gray_image;
rgb_image(:,:,2)=gray_image;
rgb_image(:,:,3)=gray_image;


>> rgb_image(1,2,1)

 ans = 44

>> rgb_image(1,2,2)

 ans = 44

>> rgb_image(1,2,3)

ans = 44
```

You can see that the above code works, but when I do the following command:

```
imwrite(rgb_image,'rgb_image.ppm');
```

the image is all white. How to save the image with the right format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Cause of problem:

`gray_image` is of type `uint8` while `rgb_image` is of type `double`, but both has values in the range `[0..255]`. When matlab saves a `double` precision image it expects its values to be in range `[0..1]` all values greater than `1` are truncated to `1` - the brightest possible value. This is why saveing a double precision `rgb_image` results with a completely white image.

#### Correction:

Use `uint8` type for `rgb_imge` as well:

```
rgb_image=zeros(size(gray_image,1),size(gray_image,2),3,'uint8');
```

Alternatively, you can convert `gray_image` to double

```
gray_image = im2double( gray_image );
```

Comment: *This is why saveing a double precision rgb_image results with a completely white image.* @Shai I think this thing has changed in Matlab 2016a. Why white image? `imgGray = imread(...); imgRGB = im2double( imgGray); figure, imshow(imgRGB);`. Gray image here. Black image if doing also `rgb_image=zeros(size(gray_image,1),size(gray_image,2),3,'uint8');`. Original image gray which I want to colorise but I have not succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to create a RGB image in Matlab 2016a where the original image has mostly gray colors

```
imgGray = imread('Ceres-Bright-Spots-4_500-miles.jpg');  

[r g b]=size(imgGray);
rgb=zeros(r,g,3); 
rgb(:,:,1)=imgGray;
rgb(:,:,2)=rgb(:,:,1);
rgb(:,:,3)=rgb(:,:,1);
imgRGB=rgb/255; 
figure,imshow(imgRGB);
```

Doing Shai's commands were not sufficient. I prepared the data to complete all steps in the guide [here](http://se.mathworks.com/videos/image-processing-made-easy-81718.html?form_seq=conf1050) about *Image Processing Made Easy*.